# terraform: How to destroy oldest instance when lowering aws_instance count

Tags: terraform

Given a pair of aws instances deployed with

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count         = 2
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags = {
      Name = "Test${count.index}"
  }
}
```

Lowering `count = 1` will destroy the last instance deployed:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

    - aws_instance.example[1]
```

Is it possible to get terraform to destroy the ***first instance***. ie.

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  - aws_instance.example[0]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'd like to be able to scale instances and ELB isn't suitable for our setup.
Ideally, when I scale down I'd like to take out the oldest instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform is tracking which instance is which via its state. When you reduce your `count` on the `aws_instance` resource Terraform will simply remove the later instances. While this shouldn't really be much of an issue because I would only really recommend that you are deploying groups of homogenous instances that can handle the load being interrupted (and would sit behind some form of load balancer mechanism) if you really needed to you could edit the state file to reorder the instances before reducing the number of instances.

The state file is serialised as JSON so you can just edit it directly (making sure it's uploaded to whatever you're using for remote state if you are using remote state) or better yet you can use the first class tools for editing remote state that the Terraform CLI provides with `terraform state mv`.

As an example you can do this:

```
# Example from question has been applied already
# `count` is edited from 2 to 1
$ terraform plan
...
aws_instance.example[1]: Refreshing state... (ID: i-0c227dfbfc72fb0cd)
aws_instance.example: Refreshing state... (ID: i-095fd3fdf86ce8254)

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  - destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  - aws_instance.example[1]

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
...
$
$
$
$ terraform state list
aws_instance.example[0]
aws_instance.example[1]
$
$
$
$ terraform state mv aws_instance.example[1] aws_instance.example[2]
Moved aws_instance.example[1] to aws_instance.example[2]
$ terraform state mv aws_instance.example[0] aws_instance.example[1]
Moved aws_instance.example[0] to aws_instance.example[1]
$ terraform state mv aws_instance.example[2] aws_instance.example[0]
Moved aws_instance.example[2] to aws_instance.example[0]
$
$
$
$ terraform plan
...
aws_instance.example[1]: Refreshing state... (ID: i-095fd3fdf86ce8254)
aws_instance.example: Refreshing state... (ID: i-0c227dfbfc72fb0cd)

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
  - destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ aws_instance.example
      tags.Name: "Test1" => "Test0"

  - aws_instance.example[1]

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 1 to destroy.
...
```

Comment: In the absence of any options to control which instance from the list is removed this may be the best option. It does seem a shame that there isn't some lifecycle option where you could specify fifo or lifo.

Comment: Terraform really isn't designed to care. I'd strongly recommend thinking about your use case and if you really can't handle this in a better fashion by using things like autoscaling groups.